# django foreign key mismatch - "question_question" referencing "question_subject"

Tags: python, django

Hi there is this problem I have
can anyone solve this ?

here is my django model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=False)
    content = models.TextField(null=True,blank=False)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name="subject_question")
    topicTag = models.ManyToManyField(TopicTag, related_name='questionTopic', blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='questionUser', blank=True, through='QuestionVote')
    answer_count = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    difficulty = models.ForeignKey(Difficulty,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name="difficulty")
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,  unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and here is the error code

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "question_question" referencing "question_subject"
```

and here is the subject model

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True,null=False,blank=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: could you please show your Subject model ?

Comment: @amadousow here is the subject model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is likely do to a migration issue.  If you are in early development, the quickest solution is to delete migration files and SQLite db, re-run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.  Alternatively you can revert all migrations with `python manage.py name_of_app migrate -- zero`.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations) for more information on reverting migrations.